# Do creatures summoned by a Planeswalker have summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Elspeth, Sun's Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elspeth%2C%20Sun%27s%20Champion) has a loyalty ability which says:

> Place three 1/1 white soldier creature tokens onto the battlefield.

When this ability is activated, do these soldiers have summoning sickness? I ask because Elspeth herself does *not* have summoning sickness when placed onto the battlefield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they'll have summoning sickness. *Every* creature experiences summoning sickness, without exception, unless something says it doesn't, such as having [Haste](http://magiccards.info/rule/702-keyword-abilities.html#rule-702-10). Elspeth herself doesn't experience Summoning Sickness because she isn't a creature - she's a  planeswalker.

For an example of a Planeswalker that places creatures which *do* have Haste, see [Xenagos, the Reveler](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Xenagos%2C%20the%20Reveler).

Summoning sickness comes from [rule 302.6](http://magiccards.info/rule/302-creatures.html#rule-302-6):

> 302.6. A creatures activated ability with the tap symbol or the untap symbol in its activation cost cant be activated unless the creature has been under its controllers control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. A creature cant attack unless it has been under its controllers control continuously since his or her most recent turn began. This rule is informally called the "summoning sickness" rule.

In short: Summoning Sickness means a creature can't attack, or activate abilities with a tap or untap symbol in their cost, until they've been under your control since your untap step.

If a permanent on the battlefield is *turned into* a creature — e.g. you transform your [Mutavault](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mutavault) — it will suddenly start being affected by summoning sickness, if you haven't controlled that permanent since the beginning of your turn. For this reason, an alternate way to describe it is that *everything* has summoning sickness, but it only *affects* things if they're creatures.

Creatures affected by summoning sickness can still *be* tapped by other things, though. You can cast [Devout Invocation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Devout%20Invocation), for instance, and tap a creature that you only just summoned.

Comment: As a side note, if Elspeth were to somehow *become* a creature (by a combination of Mycosynth Lattice and March of the Machines, for example), she *would* have summoning sickness. You would still be able to activate her abilities, because they don't require tapping, but you wouldn't be able to attack with her the turn you played her.

Comment: I usually try to explain to new players that *everything* has summoning sickness, but it only *affects* creatures. The [Summoning Sickness video from the Judge's Corner on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asYHxwoElIM) also explains it like this.